# How to detect an image file is svg-fomat strictly?

Tags: c++, image, svg

```
QFile file(filepath);  
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {  
    qWarning() << "DetectImageFormat() failed to open file:" << filepath;  
    return "";  
}  

const QByteArray data = file.read(1024); 
// Check svg file. but sometimes i get the data failed!

if (data.indexOf("<svg") > -1) {  
    return "svg";  
}
```

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As for your problem, what do you mean by "sometimes i get the data failed"? How does it fail? For what files? Have you checked the files to see its contents? Have you checked in a hex-editor?

Comment: Without access to the failing file there is no way for any of us, or you for that matter, to be able to find out what the problem might be. You need to ask that "somebody" to send you the failing file(s) so you can check it out.

Comment: What if there is a 1024+ byte comment before `<svg`?